# How to use href in a loop in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to create a side bar in which I want to add different links. My query is that the IDs if the hrefs are same but the names are different. Like

> 127.0.0.1:8000/1/Austria
>
> 127.0.0.1:8000/1/America

I want to refer every href to a different link. Is it possible using a loop?If yes, Please tell me how?

Here is the code

**views.py**

```
def details(request,item_id):
    item=get_object_or_404(Item,pk=item_id)
    clients=Client.objects.all()
    return render(request,'details.html',{'item':item,'clients':clients})
```

**template.html**

```
<div>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Products</h1>
<div class="container-fluid d-none d-xl-block" style="width: 17%;height: 1400px;float: left;background-color: lavender">
<ul style="list-style: none;" class="form-control" id="client">
{% for client in clients %}
<li class="btn btn-block btn-responsive"  style="background-color: #daad86;color: white;width: 250px;height:50px;margin-top: 10px"><a href="{{ client.place }}">{{ client.place }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

**url.py**

```
path('<int:item_id>/',views.details,name='details'),
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can and I think you're getting close. You just need to prepend `1/` as a prefix to the `href` attribute. You should also look at the actual HTML generated by your template engine and with that it should be clear how you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your url.py file, you just need to add another variable after '/':

**url.py**

```
path('<int:item_id>/<str:place>',views.details,name='details'),
```

Then just prepend **/1/** in your **a** tag in template.html file:

**template.html**

```
{% for client in clients %}
<li class="btn btn-block btn-responsive"  style="background-color: #daad86;color: white;width: 250px;height:50px;margin-top: 10px"><a href="/1/{{ client.place }}">{{ client.place }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then further change your business logic in views.py:

**views.py**

```
def details(request,item_id, place_name):
    item=get_object_or_404(Item,pk=item_id)
    clients=Client.objects.all()
    return render(request,'details.html',{'item':item,'clients':clients})
```

Comment: thanks @Shubhum. If the ID's are same do they refer to different links?